# How to insert into SQL-Database datetime value from bootstrap form - input datetime?

Tags: sql, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-webpages

I'm doing a simple form and insert values into SQL Database. I'm using ASP WEB PAGES for this. There is more values but i'm putting just part of it, as the rest works fine.

```
//variables
int id_project_fk = 0;
DateTime applicationDate = DateTime.Now;
var name = "";
var surname = "";
DateTime birthdate;
//**
//Requesting form
birthdate = Request.Form["birthdate"].AsDateTime();
//INSERT COMMAND 
var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO applications (id_project_fk,     applicationDate, name, surname, birthdate) VALUES(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)";
db.Execute(insertCommand, id_project_fk, applicationDate, name, surname, birthdate);
//HTML CODE
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="dob">Date of birth: </label>
 <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" />
</div>
```

The error I'm having:

```
 An overflow occurred while converting to datetime
```

I'm beginner and self-learner, I've been trying for couple of hours to solve this problem, but I didn't manage. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, my problem was stupid. I just requested the form for name "birthdate", but i named it "dob". Just this :)